# Django/Bootstrap Formatting Issue

Tags: python, html, css, django, bootstrap-4

I am working through some beginner Django tutorials to build a basic polling website. I have everything working, but I can't get the formatting to display properly on my "results" page for the polls.

How my page looks:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/AuB6q.png

The votes are being displayed, but you can't see them due to the formatting:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgMgr.png

How it is supposed to look:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmCOb.png

Below is my code on my results.html:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1 class="mb-5 text-center">{{ question.question_text }}</h1>

<ul class="list-group mb-5">
    {% for choice in question.choice_set.all %}
    <li class="list-group-item">
        {{ choice.choice_text }}  <span class="badge badge-success float-right">{{ choice.votes }} vote{{ choice.votes | pluralize }}</span>
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>

<a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'polls:index' %}">Back To Polls</a>
<a class="btn btn-dark" href="{% url 'polls:detail' question.id %}">Vote again?</a>
{% endblock %}
```

Any ideas on what I have wrong?

Comment: The CSS code for bootstrap im using is:

<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your **CDN**. Change this **CDN**

```
<link href="cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/…" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

to this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. Why did the cdn I have not work? I copied from the bootstrap website.